# Error (Possible Permissions Issue) When using Process.Start in C#

Tags: c#, snort

I'm trying to start an application called snort from a C# application, using System.Diagnostics.Process, and I need to capture its output. To achieve this, I've used the code below.

When I try to run this, I get an error which is related to loading the configuration file. I get this same error if I try to manually run the exe from a CMD without administrator privileges, so I think this is a permissions issue for the forked process, but I'm not entirely sure of that. However, I have tried the following, to no avail:

1. I have added  to the C# application manifest (the C# application is definitely running as administrator).
2. I have tried using a username and password with Process.StartInfo

However, the error still remains. Also, for clarity: The process is started, I am receiving output in My OutputHandler method, etc -- the issue is with the forked exe, it is having a problem reading the specified configuration file.

The sample code is as follows:

```
var process = new Process();

process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Snort\bin\snort.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-A console -i2 -c C:\Snort\etc\snort.conf -l C:\Snort\log\ -K ascii";

process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute         = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput  = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError   = true;
process.OutputDataReceived               += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
process.ErrorDataReceived                += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();
```

This does start the required process, but as I mention that process (snort) then outputs an error when trying to read the configuration file (the same error I get if I try to manually run the same process from a CMD without admin rights--hence why I think the issue might be permissions-based).

Can anyone suggest anything else I might try to get around this. I *do* need to capture output, so (if I understand it correctly) the 'runas' verb doesn't help.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well you should try giving the user you are running it as permissions to the config files...... surely? Or copy them to a location it does have access too and pass that path instead

Comment: If that is not the issue you could look into the PATH variable in the case it is different between accounts and the config files are specified relative to that?

Comment: Are you sure your problem is not caused by not initializing `process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory`? Then can you check with Process Explorer what credentials the new process (as well as your program) is running with?

Comment: Did your try running your programm with release configuration?

Comment: @MetaColon: how should a release configuration help?

Comment: Use Process Monitor, filter for your process and for the config file. If you see "File Not Found", it's likely a worksing directory issue. If you see "Access Denied", it's likely a permission problem.

Comment: It once worked for me, don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I explored a few option and tried to continue on the path of permission and changed the application manifest file permission and replaced the standard permission file with:

requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"

This did not change anything.
I am using windows 8.1 and when I visited the properties of the snort.exe file I changed the compatibility and run the application compatible with win 7 and ticked the box to run as administrator, it is now working fine.

[snort.exe properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvLxh.png)

Many Thanks to everybody